# Programmatically generated preferences screen SwitchPreference flickering on change

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have a preferences xml (**pref_general_second.xml**) that I run in a regular layout file(**activity_preferences.xml**) via a listView.

This all works fine, but when I click the switch preference to turn it on / off, the screen flickers for a fraction of a second. It looks like for that moment, the whole screen is white / blank. So presumably there's some delay adding a preference preferences xml through a layout? Is there a way I can improve this?

pref_general_second.xml:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:paddingRight="25dp">

    <SwitchPreference
        android:key="abc"
        android:title="g0g0g0g0" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

activity_preferences.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dividerHeight="2sp"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" />

</LinearLayout>
```

SettingsActivitySecond.java

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_preferences);
    setupSimplePreferencesScreen();
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general_second);
```